# Google Places Api doesn't receive Opening hours

Tags: google-places-api, billing

I was trying to get the opening hours of pizza restaurants in New York with the Google Places Api and this parameter is never returned. I always get something like this:

```
"icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "73973bd1fac905f102ee1afe536594dc42bca5ff",
         "name" : "Lombardi's Pizza",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false
         },
```

When I do the same text query using google in a web browser I can see the opening hours for the same restaurants.

Has someone else encountered this issue? Could it be because I have not activated billing in the Google Developers Console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a basic search(`textSearch`, `nearbySearch`, etc.)you will not receive detailed `opening_hours`.

You'll need a further [request for details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details) by using the `reference` for the place (returned by the basic search) as parameter.

Comment: Is there any possible to get these extra details without calling detail API. 
For me I need to show the Open Hours and Photo for the place in List, But here it is not good practice to call Detail API